# Process Builder recursion issue: repeats actions 6 times

Tags: process-builder, bug, recursion

I'll skip the overall context and just describe the current issue at hand.

I have a Process Builder on Object X, with **Recursion turned ON**. We need recursion turned on for all our automation to work correctly.

Right now, there is only 1 criteria node (there will be more in future, but just working with 1 for now to troubleshoot this) which checks the value of NOT(ISBLANK(Lookup_field__c)). If it evaluates to TRUE, the Process Builder should create 1 related record for Object Y.

Instead, what is happening is **6 new records** are being created.

**Things I have already checked:**

- There are NO other criteria nodes in this process builder
- There are NO other actions in the Process Builder, except the one creating related records.
- There are no other Process Builders (or any other system automation) which are triggered on create of a record for Object Y (the related record that should be created)
- Checking the "Do you want to execute the actions only when specified changes are made to the record?" checkbox has not made any difference.

**Something that I found online:** I found a [Salesforce article](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=process_advanced_considerations.htm&type=5) which has a strange and concerning paragraph right at the bottom, which seems to indicate to me that this behaviour of calling an action 6 times when recursion is turned on, is a known Salesforce bug/issue.

**Does anybody have any insights into this strange behaviour when using recursion?**

Comment: Why do you need recursion turned on for this functionality to work? Does your Process populate `lookup_field__c`? Do you have any Workflow Rules or Triggers on either object?

Comment: @DavidReed we need recursion on for other automation that is going to sit on this process builder. The process does not populate lookup_field__c, and as I mentioned in my post, there is no other workflow or triggering automation that sits on Object X or Y.